# Failed to Export Signed Application Package with exist keystore

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

i am trying to Export Signed Application Package to upload it to store. the application is already exist, but i want to upload a new version of it, so i used same keystore and same Alias .

But Export .apk Failed without any Log/Condole errors  or notes !

i tried to use debug.keystore as  keystore instead of original one, i got the same problem ..

[image]

notes that in this application version, i created a new project and used same package name, is there any problem with this ?

thanks ..

---

Edited: 14-10-2014:
I just found the reason, in project.properties the existing line make problems, so i just comment it  :

## proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt

Comment: did you try all the basic things? like close-reopen eclipse, clean all the projects, disable the "build automatically" before export, kill and start adb?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i found the reason and solve it.. i just comment proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt in project.properties